# Why does my calculated node reference behave differently?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here's a MWE to show what I mean:

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0, ..., 4}
    \node[circle,draw] (n\x) at ({2*\x}, 0) {\x};
    \foreach \x in {0, ..., 3} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\x+1}
      \draw[red] (n\x) to[bend left] (n\y);
      \draw[blue] (n\x) circle (.2);
      \draw[gray,fill] (n\y) circle (.05);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would expect this to create a few circular nodes, named `n0` through `n4`, and connect subsequent pairs by lines going from edge to edge. However, while the `(n\x)` reference correctly refers to the node at `\x`, `(n\y)` in all instances somehow collapses to a single point, which is not even in the center:

[image]

**Why does `\y` behave differently that `\x`?**

I know how to make this work, for example using `/pgf/foreach/remember`, but I'm curious.

Comment: If you print out the value of `\y` you'll see that it's a real number (1.0, 2.0, etc.).

Comment: Interesting!! So the `.0` chooses a particular point, like `.west`?

Comment: Looks like it. `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` truncates the decimal part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `x = 0`, `\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\x+1}` defines `\y` to `1.0`. Then node `n1.0` means a point at the boundary of node `n1` and at angle `0`.

To get `\y` defined to `1`, here you can use one of the following (the last two are both suggested by @Alenanno from [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566636/why-does-my-calculated-node-reference-behave-differently/566652?noredirect=1#comment1428785_566652)),

- `pgfmath` function `int`: `\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{int(\x+1)}`,
- `pgfmath` macro `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`: `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{\x+1}`, and
- `pgffor` option `evaluate` accompanied by `int` function: `\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using int(\x+1)] in {0, ..., 3} {...}`.

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0, ..., 4}
      \node[circle,draw] (n\x) at ({2*\x}, 0) {\x};
    \foreach \x in {0, ..., 3} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{int(\x+1)}
      \draw[red] (n\x) to[bend left] (n\y);
      \draw[blue] (n\x) circle (.2);
      \draw[gray,fill] (n\y) circle (.05);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I never knew about the angle, this is super useful!

Comment: @TheVee You can also use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\y{\x+1}`. :) And since it's a foreach, you can directly do `\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using int(\x+1)] in {0, ..., 3} {%  ...`

Comment: @Alenanno I've added your suggestions to my answer, and thanks!